# Running multiple docker containers in same host

Tags: docker

I am new to docker. I have a doubt regarding docker. Based on the understanding of docker, Docker will help to create the container of the application we can to deploy along with application dependencies.
My question is that if i have web application inside docker container, is it possible to run multiple containers inside single host? If yes, How will i make sure the request be directed to each app?. 
Will there be any change in performance depending on number of core of host?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to run multiple containers inside single host?

Yes, you can run many.

> If yes, How will direct requests to the right container?

You have many options, the simplest is just to run the container with port forwarding (which is built in to docker), but you could also run a load balancer or proxy on the host.

> Will there be any change in performance depending on number of core of host?

There can be, of course. It depends on whether or not you're already reaching a performance bottleneck of some sort before adding another container. All the containers are making use of the same hardware.